# How to run a CMD Through Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, variables, invoke

```
$remoteinst = "\Windows\Temp\MyFolder"
$remotecomp = ComputerName
$remotesess = New-PSSession $remotecomp
$remotedir = "C:" + $remoteinst + "\Install.cmd"
Invoke-Command -Session $remotesess -ScriptBlock {$remotedir}
```

I'm trying to run the Install.cmd file on a remote computer. I realised I can't pass commands through Enter-PSSession but I'm struggling to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There's no need for creating an explicit session: you can pass the target computer name directly to `Invoke-Command -ComputerName <computerName>`.
- Invoking a command whose name / path is stored in a *variable* requires `&`, the call operator.
- The script block passed to `Invoke-Command -ComputerName ...` is executed *remotely*, so you cannot directly use *local* variables in it; in PSv3+, the simplest way to solve this problem is to use the `using` scope: `$using:<localVarName>`

Keeping all these points in mind, we get:

```
$remoteinst = "\Windows\Temp\MyFolder"
$remotecomp = ComputerName # Note: This syntax assumes that `ComputerName` is a *command*
$remotedir = "C:" + $remoteinst + "\Install.cmd"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteComp -ScriptBlock { & $using:remotedir }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `cmd /c` to the front of the path to the batch file.

Comment: While this succeeds in invoking an external program stored in a _variable_, it subjects its arguments to an additional round of interpretation, which is unnecessary (as is the creation of the `cmd` child process as a whole); all you need is to use `&`, PowerShell's call operator. Aside from that, the OP's root problem is the attempt to use a _local_ variable _remotely_.

Comment: Ah yes, the variable's scope. D'oh.